# Information about "Make Twenty One, no more, no less" wooden Tabletop Game

Tags: identify-this-game

We have searched and searched and cannot find any information about this game. It is wooden, has a slot for pennies that fall around pins with the points listed where the pennies fall.  We can't find a company name. Specifically we would love to know when it was made and who it was made by. A little history.

I am not sure if this group can help or could lead me to who can. Thanks so much!

Comment: If this is a game you own, including a picture of it would help.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like [Plinko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plinko). I know it from the Price is Right, but commercial versions are likely out there.